# Spring boot- inject service into doFiler

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to inject a auth service to a `Filer` -

```
@Autowired
AuthRequestService authService;
```

And use it in `doFiler` method -

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    System.out.println("SAPServiceFilter: "+ req.getRequestURI());
    //TODO - create auth sender
    authService.isAuthnticate((HttpServletRequest)request); //null
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

My filter class in sub-package of my `@SpringBootApplication` class and annotated with `@service` -

```
@Service
public class AuthRequestService {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("AuthRequestService @PostConstruct");
    }

    public boolean isAuthnticate(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("isAuthnticate");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The class also appears when listing all my beans using -

```
for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Still when debugging `authService` is null, one last thing the filter is registered with `FilterRegistrationBean` -

```
FilterRegistrationBean<SAPServiceFilter> filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
filterRegBean.setFilter(new SAPServiceFilter());
```